# What does the Mitre do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

One of the items the Binding of Isaac expansion Wrath of the Lamb added was the Mitre. When I picked it up I just go the message "You feel blessed" I haven't noticed a change in my shots or anything. What effect does this item have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Mitre), the Mitre "greatly increases the chance of replacing spawned hearts with Soul Hearts." In addition, it may increase the probability of encountering an [Angel Room](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Angel_Room), but that seems to be unconfirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Gives a small chance of treasure rooms appearing in The Womb/Utero/Sheol/The Cathedral.
I know this from having completed the game quite a few times since downloading the DLC, and the wiki confirms what I've observed.

Comment: Do you have a source or did you observe it yourself?

Comment: I've observed it multiple times for myself (having already completed the game 13 times since the DLC release) and the wiki also confirms this.

Comment: Cool. If I were you, I'd edit that information into the answer. People generally prefer to upvote answers that are backed up with experience or external sources.

Answer (score 0):

It also increases the chance of running into 'Angel rooms' (Every blessed item does so)

Comment: -1 This is false. Looking at the source code, the only thing affecting chance of angel room is whether you are eligible or not (eligible if you have seen a devil room and not taken a deal), and then the chance is 50/50.

Answer (score -1):

The blessing gives you a soul heart when you are at half a heart. Tested this on myself.

Comment: That's Scapular, not the Mitre. Each item that says "you feel blessed" has an additional effect on top of the blessing (which increases the chances of Angel Rooms and possibly some other things).